# RHEL + kernel messages + how to identify if kernel message are indicated on a problem

Tags: rhel, kernel, memory

we have old RHEL 7.2 server, and we notice about very strange kernel messages

not sure if below line defined a problem

```
[ffffea00a5a00000-ffffea00a5bfffff] PMD -> [ffff880015000000-ffff8800151fffff] on node 0
```

but I share also the full message and hope to get more details about them

```
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Node 1 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Node 1 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] 11230501 total pagecache pages
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] 55992 pages in swap cache
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Swap cache stats: add 1175357, delete 1119365, find 4949217/4971174
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Free swap  = 13818588kB
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] Total swap = 16351228kB
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] 33652606 pages RAM
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[Thu Oct 27 10:20:59 2022] 587996 pages reserved
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x2a40000000-0x2c3fffffff]
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [mem 0x2a40000000-0x2c3fffffff] page 1G
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00a5a00000-ffffea00a5bfffff] PMD -> [ffff880015000000-ffff8800151fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00a9000000-ffffea00a93fffff] PMD -> [ffff881002c00000-ffff881002ffffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00a9400000-ffffea00a99fffff] PMD -> [ffff881003800000-ffff881003dfffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00a9a00000-ffffea00a9bfffff] PMD -> [ffff881000200000-ffff8810003fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00a9c00000-ffffea00a9dfffff] PMD -> [ffff881004200000-ffff8810043fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00a9e00000-ffffea00a9ffffff] PMD -> [ffff881003e00000-ffff881003ffffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aa000000-ffffea00aa9fffff] PMD -> [ffff881004600000-ffff881004ffffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aaa00000-ffffea00aabfffff] PMD -> [ffff881005200000-ffff8810053fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aac00000-ffffea00aadfffff] PMD -> [ffff881005000000-ffff8810051fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aae00000-ffffea00ab9fffff] PMD -> [ffff881005400000-ffff881005ffffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aba00000-ffffea00acbfffff] PMD -> [ffff881006200000-ffff8810073fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00acc00000-ffffea00acffffff] PMD -> [ffff881007600000-ffff8810079fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ad000000-ffffea00ad1fffff] PMD -> [ffff881007400000-ffff8810075fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ad200000-ffffea00adffffff] PMD -> [ffff881007a00000-ffff8810087fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ae000000-ffffea00ae1fffff] PMD -> [ffff881008a00000-ffff881008bfffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ae200000-ffffea00ae3fffff] PMD -> [ffff881008800000-ffff8810089fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ae400000-ffffea00ae5fffff] PMD -> [ffff881008c00000-ffff881008dfffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ae600000-ffffea00ae7fffff] PMD -> [ffff881009200000-ffff8810093fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00ae800000-ffffea00ae9fffff] PMD -> [ffff881009000000-ffff8810091fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aea00000-ffffea00aebfffff] PMD -> [ffff881009400000-ffff8810095fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aec00000-ffffea00aedfffff] PMD -> [ffff881009800000-ffff8810099fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00aee00000-ffffea00aeffffff] PMD -> [ffff881009600000-ffff8810097fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00af000000-ffffea00af1fffff] PMD -> [ffff881009c00000-ffff881009dfffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00af200000-ffffea00af3fffff] PMD -> [ffff881009a00000-ffff881009bfffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00af400000-ffffea00af5fffff] PMD -> [ffff88100a200000-ffff88100a3fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00af600000-ffffea00af7fffff] PMD -> [ffff881009e00000-ffff881009ffffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00af800000-ffffea00b03fffff] PMD -> [ffff88100a400000-ffff88100adfffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:00 2022]  [ffffea00b0400000-ffffea00b09fffff] PMD -> [ffff88100b000000-ffff88100b5fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b0a00000-ffffea00b0bfffff] PMD -> [ffff881004400000-ffff8810045fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b0c00000-ffffea00b0dfffff] PMD -> [ffff88100b800000-ffff88100b9fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x2c40000000-0x2e3fffffff]
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [mem 0x2c40000000-0x2e3fffffff] page 1G
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b0e00000-ffffea00b0ffffff] PMD -> [ffff88100b600000-ffff88100b7fffff] on node 1
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b1000000-ffffea00b1dfffff] PMD -> [ffff88100ba00000-ffff88100c7fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b1e00000-ffffea00b33fffff] PMD -> [ffff88100cc00000-ffff88100e1fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b3400000-ffffea00b4ffffff] PMD -> [ffff88100e400000-ffff88100fffffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b5000000-ffffea00b51fffff] PMD -> [ffff88100c800000-ffff88100c9fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b5200000-ffffea00b59fffff] PMD -> [ffff881010000000-ffff8810107fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b5a00000-ffffea00b5bfffff] PMD -> [ffff881010c00000-ffff881010dfffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b5c00000-ffffea00b5dfffff] PMD -> [ffff881010a00000-ffff881010bfffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b5e00000-ffffea00b61fffff] PMD -> [ffff881011000000-ffff8810113fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b6200000-ffffea00b69fffff] PMD -> [ffff881011800000-ffff881011ffffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b6a00000-ffffea00b7ffffff] PMD -> [ffff881012200000-ffff8810137fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b8000000-ffffea00b81fffff] PMD -> [ffff881013a00000-ffff881013bfffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b8200000-ffffea00b83fffff] PMD -> [ffff881013e00000-ffff881013ffffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b8400000-ffffea00b85fffff] PMD -> [ffff881013c00000-ffff881013dfffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b8600000-ffffea00b87fffff] PMD -> [ffff881014400000-ffff8810145fffff] on node 0
[Thu Oct 27 10:21:01 2022]  [ffffea00b8800000-ffffea00b89fffff] PMD -> [ffff881014000000-ffff8810141fffff] on node 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages are [debug information printed during page table setup](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/mm/init_64.c); they show information about the “page middle directory” which is one of the data structures used by the x86 MMU to map virtual addresses to physical addresses.

These messages don’t indicate a problem.